# Is it necessary to explicitly specify single quotes in a DML statement that uses String.Format()?

Tags: c#, sql, string, .net-1.1, dml

I want to refactor some code like this:

```
dSQL = "INSERT INTO inventory ( id, pksize, Description, supplier_id, UnitCost, UnitList," +
      " Qty, UPC, dept, subdept, upc_pack_size, supplier_item, bqu_id)" +
      " VALUES" + "('" + id +"'" + ", " + 
      pksize + ",'" + desc +"'" + 
      ",'" + supplierID +"'" + ", " + cost + ", " 
      + list + ", " + qty + 
      ",'" + UPC +"'" + ", " + dept + ", " + 
      subdept + ", " + UPCpkSize + 
      ",'" + supplierItem +"','" + redemption + "')";
```

...to this:

```
dSQL = string.Format(
      "INSERT INTO inventory ( id, pksize, Description, supplier_id, UnitCost, UnitList," +
      " Qty, UPC, dept, subdept, upc_pack_size, supplier_item, bqu_id)" +
      " VALUES {0}, {1}, {2}, {3}, {4}, {5}, {6}, {7}, {8}, {9}, {10}, {11}, {12}",
      id, pksize, desc, supplierID, cost, list, qty, UPC, dept, subdept, UPCpkSize, supplierItem, redemption);
```

Will this methodology suffice, or must I enclose the format values in single quotes?

### UPDATE

I just noticed this comment I added "way back when" regarding this code:

```
// This works as a string.Format() assignment without param "?"s or single quotes because dSQL is not executed, it is simply passed to DBCommand for conditional display (if there is an exception)
```

Comment: Why would it be any different? Both methods produce a string.

Comment: The answer to the problem behind the question: Parameters.

Comment: Also using a `Verbatim string literal` (`@` sign) will help readability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all of the values are of numerical types such as `int`, `decimal`, `bigint`, etc. then you don't need to enclose them in single quotes.
This code works (I just tested it)

```
dSQL = string.Format(
  "INSERT INTO inventory ( id, pksize, Description, supplier_id, UnitCost, UnitList," +
  " Qty, UPC, dept, subdept, upc_pack_size, supplier_item, bqu_id)" +
  " VALUES ({0}, {1}, {2}, {3}, {4}, {5}, {6}, {7}, {8}, {9}, {10}, {11}, {12})",
  id, pksize, desc, supplierID, cost, list, qty, UPC, dept, subdept, UPCpkSize, supplierItem,    
redemption);
```

You were missing the starting and closing braces in your code.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using parameters.

This...

- frees you from the question whether or not to use single quotes.
- secures you from SQL injection attacks and the like.

Have a look at this article, for example: [Lesson 06: Adding Parameters to Commands](http://csharp-station.com/Tutorial/AdoDotNet/Lesson06)
This will describe you how to do it.

> Using parameterized queries is a three step process:
>
> ```
> Construct the SqlCommand command string with parameters.
> Declare a SqlParameter object, assigning values as appropriate.
> Assign the SqlParameter object to the SqlCommand object's Parameters property.
> ```

In you case, your code might then look like the following.

**Step 1:**

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(
                 "INSERT INTO inventory ( id, pksize, Description, supplier_id, UnitCost, UnitList, Qty, UPC, dept, subdept, upc_pack_size, supplier_item, bqu_id) " +
                 "VALUES" + "(@id, @pksize, [ ... AND YOU OTHER PARAMETERS ... ])";", conn);
```

**Step 2:**

Repeat this for all your parameters.

```
SqlParameter paramId  = new SqlParameter();
    paramId.ParameterName = "@id";
    paramId.Value         = 12345;
```

**Step 3:**

Repeat this for all your parameters.

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(paramId);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the single quotes if they are text(char,nvarchar,varchar,nchar), numbers don't for example. Test it :)

I advise you use sql parameters though :)